# Runtime error 13 - Type mismatch - Assigning arrays

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a large macro in VBA-Excel, I'm trying to fix a bug in the assignment of `MyData(i)` to aData.

Is this due to size of these 2 arrays? is it due to the fact that `MyData(1)` is Empty?

[image]

Comment: Please note that [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please [edit] your question and include the code formatted as code block.

Comment: The variable `aData` is declared as an array it's type is `Variant/Variant()`. And you try to push a type `Variant/Empty` into it: `aData = MyData(i)`. But since it only accepts an array and `MyData(i)` is not an array but a `Variant/Empty` you get the type mismatch. • Please include the relevant code part (incl. your variable declaration) to get more detailed help (see [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

Your `aData` is a Variant Array. And you're trying to assign a Variant (not an array) to it.
Try declaring the aData variable like this:

```
Dim aData As Variant
```

If you actually wanted to assign the whole array to `aData`, `aData` still being an array. you should do it like this:

```
aData = MyData
```

And if you just wanted to put whatever is in `MyData(i)` into the same spot in `aData`. you can do:

```
aData(i) = aData(i)
```

But make sure they have the same size if you do that.

Comment: This `Dim aData As Variant` won't solve the issue. Since `aData(6)` (in his code) will then throw the next error. You cannot answer this question proplery until the OP provides more information.

Comment: True, at first glance I thought he just wanted to put `MyData(i)` into `aData`, Where `aData` isn't an array. so I edited it with more options.

Comment: No obviously `aData` should be an array since he uses `aData(6)` and also declared it as array. Actually he would await `MyData(i)` to contain another array (instead of `Empty`). This is just guessing until we get more information.